# Discord OUATH2 not showing after pressing a button on website

Tags: javascript, html, web, discord

I am very new to making a website so I decide to make this but I am having problem with maiking the OUATH2 link because it is not showing after I press the button. It should first make the user login to their discord account before redirecting them to the discord server but I am not sure why it is not happening.

I am not sure that if the invis recaptcha v2 is working please check it for me sorry for asking too much but it is very confusing.

Thank you so much

```
The website : https://smilewindiscord-th.web.app/

The full code :https://github.com/reactxsw/website
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="https://discord.com/invite/R8RYXyB4Cg" method="post" id="join-form">
    <button class="invite g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdwBR4aAAAAALtv4g0-X6_-jmGlUc6DU1l9kW19" data-callback="onSubmitrecaptcha" data-action="submit">Join Server</button>
</form>
```

You're telling it you want them to join that.
What you can do with your OAuth2 is just make the redirect URL to be the discord invite link.

It will then authorize you and pass you to Discord, however you would lose out on access tokens, etc.

Comment: Hi , thank you for suggesting me that but it seem that it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: You can view the index.html in the github repo in the same link to see if I do it correctly